# Sub domain point to a folder in linux

Tags: linux, apache, .htaccess

I need to point a sub domain to a folder of main domain. Is there any way to do this in linux sever?

Example-:

when user call **http://sudomain.mywebsite.com**, it should call  **http://mywebsite.com/myfolder**. The domain should not redirect.

Can you please tell me what is the technical term is this?

Thank you.

Comment: Is DocumentRoot for subdomain and main domain same?

Comment: @shemeermali, Hope this question is solved now. Did you implemented solution I given ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is known as a `VirtualHost`

Try creating virtualhost, that will do same task for you.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /www/myfolder
    ServerName sudomain.mywebsite.com
</VirtualHost>
```

You might want to look at more [examples](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/examples.html)

Steps to [create VirtualHost under Ubuntu/Debian](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts) (if you are using some other OS, you might want need to check for respective guide)